# Booting under MAAS direction error: File not found

Tags: maas, openstack-autopilot

I am PXE boot a node .... PXE IPV4 starts and then i get the error
Booting under MAAS direction error: File not found

I have downloaded a 14.04 image and Cluster Master is connected, Status Enabled and Images synced.......

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue this morning.

Check under settings "Default Ubuntu release used for commissioning"
I wasn't able to use 14.04 anymore.

After adding Image 16.04 commissioning is working again.

With best regards,
Jockel

Comment: true...i did reloaded the images and everything worked

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! @aavam: If this answer was helpful to you, then please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) so others may more easily find it in the future. This is also a polite way to thank the person answering your question for helping you out.

Answer (score 0):

In the maas GUI..go the settings>deploy options and change the Default Ubuntu release used for commissioning and save your selection.